# Apply gaussian blur to UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

Would it be possible to add a gaussian blur to a UIDatePicker so that it blurs the view behind it instead of being completely transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom class.
For example FXBlurView, I really like it myself.
Have a look: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView